# Tower cumulus clouds without lightnings

Tags: meteorology, clouds

Is there any possibility  to have tower cumulus (or cumulonimbus in worst case) without lightnings? And if this is happen what is the factor that cause this phenomenon?

Comment: was just reading about this today. It is possible to have  cumolonimbus without thunder or lightnings. The reason is that not all clouds reach freezing level and many may have warm rain without electrification.

Comment: @liontassThe key to this answer is to get more soundings over the ocean in the tropics where low level easterlies abound and then ask the question - do you need to have presence of supercooled water to have rain ? It is true that over the tropical oceans CAPE is very high ?

Comment: This phenomenon I noticed one month ago in the Mediterranean region and in latitude N36.00. I had returns to the weather radar for 21-24000 heights with a distinct core and reain and no lightning.

Comment: Entirely possible. Was it over land or over ocean waters ? Could be stratiform precipitation  as well. Only a DPR radar analysis can tell us what kind of cores there are - stratiform, convective, width of storm, height of storm.

Comment: Read the answers here - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10038/which-clouds-can-produce-lighting-and-thunder/10065#10065

Comment: 36 N is over land and ocean. So you need to clarify. In the meantime you can read this peer reviewed reference - https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0493%281994%29122%3C1837%3ADCCSIT%3E2.0.CO%3B2